# How to make the first element of any type and add to this element before a statement

Tags: html, css, sass

I have a case, where I have a div and inside the div, I need to get the first element, whatever that is (eg. p, div, a, h2, h3), and I want to add before the statement to that element. Is that possible to write that in SASS? I don't want to use js.

See my HTML bellow :

```
<div id="q1">
<h3>
<a href="#c5ac">
Curabitur quis lobortis elit, et porttitor ligula.
</a>
</h3>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit euismod ipsum, id     pellentesque lorem viverra faucibus. Donec ornare laoreet purus ut pulvinar.
</p>
<p>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi hendrerit euismod ipsum, id     pellentesque lorem viverra faucibus. Donec ornare laoreet purus ut pulvinar.
</p>
</div>
```

Or maybe there is a simpler way to achieve something like that? Any tips?

Comment: try pseudo nth-of-type(1) or :frist-child

Comment: *"I want to add before the statement to that element"* - please clarify what this means.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a div and inside the div, I need to get the first element, whatever that is (eg. p, div, a, h2, h3),

You need:

```
#q1 > :first-child
```

to select the first child that is a direct descendant of your parent div.

Assuming that this *""I want to add before the statement to that element" "* refers to a psuedo element...

```
#q1 > :first-child:before
```

In SASS

```
#q1 {
  & > :first-child:before {
    /* styles here */
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to add content before the first-child of an div, you can do:

```
#q1:first-child::before {
  content: "Hello World";
  font-size: 22px;
}
```